# Finding a lower bound for the expression $\log(n!)$

Tags: algorithm-analysis

Problem:
Is $\log(n!) \in$ $\Omega( n^n )$?

Answer:
Since $n! > n^n$ for all $n > 1$ we can conclude that: $\log(n!) \in$ $O( n^n )$.
Let us look at the special case where $n = 4$.
\begin{align*}
n! &= 4(3)(2) = 24 \\
n^n &= 4^4 = 256
\end{align*}
Let us look at the special case where $n = 5$.
\begin{align*}
n! &= 5(4)(3)(2) = 5(24) = 120 \\
n^n &= 5^5 = 3125
\end{align*}
Let us look at the special case where $n = 8$.
\begin{align*}
n! &= 8! = 40320 \\
n^n &= 8^8 = 16777216
\end{align*}
It looks to me that $n^n$ is growing faster but that is not a proof. To prove it, I need to
show that there exists an $M > 0$ and $n_o > 0$ such that the following statement is true for
all $n \geq n_0$:
$$ n! \leq M n^n $$
I select $n_0 = 4$ and $M = 1$. Hence the expression reduces to:
$$ n! \leq n^n $$
We have already shown that this expression is true for the special case of $n = 4$. Now, if we
add $1$ to $n$ we have:
$$ (n+1)! \leq (n+1)^{(n+1)} $$
This must be true because the left hand side increased by a factor
of $n+1$ and the right hand side increased by more than a factor of $n+1$. Now we add $1$ to $n$
again. The left hand side increases by a factor of $n+2$ and the right hand side increases by more
than a factor of $n+2$. Hence the right side increases more. We can repeat this process for ever. Therefore, I conclude the statement is true.
Do I have this right?

Comment: Please check this: https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/what-to-do-when-the-answer-is-already-part-of-the-question. Asking others to check your work is not what this site for (ask your instructor if you have one). If you are not sure about a specific step, please specify it (and why you are not sure about it).

Comment: At the beginning of your question you are asking about a lower bound, but in the rest of the question you are talking about an upper bound?

Comment: @Dmitry I do not currently have an instructor. I am not currently taking a course.

Comment: @Steven I realize that the line $n! > n^n$ is wrong. It was a mathematical typesetting error. I should have written $n! < n^n$. I am thinking I need to be very carefully in updating the post due to the comments already made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, $n!$ is NOT greater than $n^n$. Indeed, $n! = \displaystyle\prod\limits_{k=1}^nk\leq \prod\limits_{k=1}^nn = n^n$.

Secondly, even if you have a function $f(n)$ such that $f(n) > n^n$, that does not mean that $\log(f(n)) \in \Omega(n^n)$. For example, $n^{n+1}>n^n$, but $\log(n^{n+1}) = (n+1)\log n < n^2 = o(n^n)$.

Finaly, you can write $\log(n!) = \log(\prod\limits_{k=1}^nk) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log(k) \leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log(n) = n\log n$.

With this inequality, we can deduce that $\log(n!) \in O(n\log n)$ and since $n\log n = o(n^n)$, the statement $\log(n!) \in \Omega(n^n)$ is false.

Answer (score 1):

$\log n! \le \log n^n = n \log n = o(n^n)$.